# Google Analytics 1-Day Active Users Inconsistently Reported

Tags: google-analytics

I am getting some really strange results reported for 1-day Active Users in the Google Analytics console.

As an example, I am looking at two segments, and "All Users".

If I set my date range to July 2 only, the 1-day active users are 340 / 883 / 1359

If I set my date range to July 1-July 10, the 1-day active users for July 2 (based on hovering on the graph) are 46 / 130 / 210

If I set my date range to July 1-July 31, the 1-day active users for July 2 are 9 / 24 / 38.

If I set my date range to July 1 - Sept 30, the 1-day active users for July 2 are 6 / 17 / 26.

To my understanding, 1-day active users should be the number of active users that were active on the site on that specific day, independent of any other day, the reporting range, etc.

Am I misunderstanding this? Or any clue what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're seeing is a result of sampling.

For your 1 day range reports, the data is probably based on a very low % of actual sessions. You can check it this way:

[image]

The data from the longer date ranges should have a higher % and should be more accurate.

Comment: That appears to be the source of the discrepancy! Thank you so much!